# File only downloading when opened in new window/tab

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-headers, download

I have a function that creates different file types depending on a variable, I have it generating an XML, but when I click the link to the page to do so (`<a href="/asset/1/xml">XML</a>`), nothing happens. If I click to open it in a new tab or manually enter the url in the title bar then the file will download as I want it to.

```
function asset($asset_id, $display = ''){

    $this->load->model('model_asset');

    $asset = $this->model_asset->get_by_id($asset_id, true);

    switch($display) {
    case 'xml':
        $this->load->helper('array_to_xml_helper');

        $asset_arr = get_object_vars($asset);

        $filename = $asset->title .'-'. $asset->subtitle . '.xml';
        $xml = Array2XML::createXML('asset', $asset_arr);
        header ("Content-Type:text/xml");
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. $filename .'"');
        echo $xml->saveXML();
        break;
    }
}
```

How can I make this work with dynamically generated files (I'm using a arraytoxml utility function I found [here](http://www.lalit.org/lab/convert-php-array-to-xml-with-attributes/))

Comment: are you outputting anything other than the headers?

Comment: whoops.. looks like i didn't post all the code i meant to.  yes i am :p

Comment: You could modify the link so that it will open in a new window.  `<a target="_blank">` should do it.  This just circumvenes the problem, so it's not really a solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set file in attachement
Add this to your headers :

- Content-disposition: attachment
- filename=huge_document.pdf